# Rotation symbol in ArcGIS online not always available?

Tags: wfs, arcgis-online, angles, arcgis-survey123

I'm currently making an application with Survey123 and ArcGIS online. This application uses the survey to add ratings on 9 subjects. The added points are loaded into an webmap in ArcGIS Online which should show them like this:
[image: this]

I made this flower shaped figure by adding my own symbols into the webmap and give each subject a different angle, so each dot represents a subjects rating.

I created the survey and the shape in different steps. I wanted to combine the points (wfs) of the survey with the created symbol but in the point file of the survey the Rotate symbol (degree) function is not available any more. I noticed that on some layers this function does work and on some it doesn't. Does anyone knows what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Whats the source of the WFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation is available on the hosted feature layer you created but on wfs layers which were probably published by the hosted feature layer in AGOL will only have simple location configuration available.